# How do you close a JQuery dialog so that the content is cleared

Tags: jquery, html, events

I hope someone can enlighten me as to why I'm not able to clear the contents of a dialog between different open events.
To start with, I have a very simple page that includes an update panel as you see below.  The only thing in the main form is a link ("click me") to invoke the dialog opening.
The open event handler performs an asynchronous Post-back.  The code behind event handler method "btn_dialog", populates the dialog's Literal ("litChart") with values which are then displayed.  This all works very well.  My problem is when I click the close (X button), which closes the dialog just fine, the content in the literal is not being cleared as I would think it would during close and the next time I click the link to open the dialog it shows the same text/controls that I put there the first time.  What I'd like is to clear the contents each time the dialog closes so it has no recollection of the previous content.
I have used $("div#contentHolder").empty(); and $("div#contentHolder").dialog("destroy").empty(); and various other ways. What I think is happening is that the selector is not referencing the dialog content correctly.
I'm a newbie with JQuery, and am not sure where to go from here.  I'd really appreciate it if anyone can help me with proven code.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph_head" Runat="Server">

 <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog_detail").dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 'auto', 
         open: function (event, ui) { __doPostBack('<%=btn_dialog.UniqueID %>', ''); },
         close: function (event, ui) { $("div#contentHolder").empty(); }
        });
    });
 </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph_main" Runat="Server">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_main" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>    
         <span onclick="$('#dialog_detail').dialog('open');">click me</span>
    </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
   <div id='dialog_detail'>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_dialog" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="UpdateProgress1"  
                  AssociatedUpdatePanelID="up_dialog">
                  <ProgressTemplate>
                       <asp:Image ID="postbackAnimation" 
                          ImageUrl="/dashboard/images/ajax-loader.gif" 
                          AlternateText="Loading..." runat="server" />
                  </ProgressTemplate>
               </asp:UpdateProgress>    
               <div id="contentHolder" runat="server">
                  <asp:Literal ID="litChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </div>   
                <asp:Button ID="btn_dialog" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
             </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel> 
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

below is the code behind that populates this:

Yes, I have tried that and event tried it again just now.  The problem with that is that once the dialog has been destroyed, it can't be reopened.  Can someone please try the code and see if they can get the result?  I have the code behind as so:

```
 Protected Sub btn_dialog_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_dialog.Click

    litChart.Text = GetScript("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce")

 Sub End

 Private Function GetScript(ByVal comment As String) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder


    sb.AppendLine("<p style='max-width: 500px; text-align: left;'>")
    sb.AppendLine(comment)
    sb.AppendLine("</p>")
    Return sb.ToString

 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should destroy it

```
    $("#dialog_detail").dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 'auto', 
     open: function (event, ui) { __doPostBack('<%=btn_dialog.UniqueID %>', ''); },
     close: function (event, ui) { $("#dialog_detail").dialog("destroy"); }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, the problem with destroy is that you can't re-open the dialog any longer.

Comment: I figured that, but how would you do it when it's already initialized as shown in the code?